# Ubuntu 12.04 usb installation problem - login page

Tags: 12.04, login, live-usb

I'm trying to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 from a USB drive. I downloaded the ISO file and loaded it onto the USB drive with from my existing Ubuntu 11.10 with the **usb startup disk creator**. When I boot from the usb drive, it loads the login page and asks for user name and password. I'm not sure what to do at this point. I tried to login with my 11.10 user name and it doesn't work. I've installed previous versions of Ubuntu from a usb drive and this has never happened--it usually takes me straight to the desktop from where I can run the installer. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

The liveCD username and password, by default, are:

Username: `ubuntu`

Password: `ubuntu`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `root` and blank password? then change the pass via

```
$ passwd
```

Or I think you may have to set the password first via `passwd root`

You can [also try this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/39864)

> If you forgot you password for your ubuntu system you can recover
>   using the following steps
>
> - Turn your computer on.
> - Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> at the grub prompt.
> - Press <kbd>e</kbd> for edit.
> - Highlight the line that begins kernel ………, press <kbd>e</kbd>
> - Go to the very end of the line, add `rw init=/bin/bash`
> - press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then press <kbd>b</kbd> to boot your system.
> - Your system will boot up to a passwordless root shell.
> - Type in `passwd username`
> - Set your password.
> - Type in reboot

Comment: the root account is disabled, even on the LiveCD.  That's what sudo is for.